# Matchit in R - Reporting results

Tags: r, statistics, propensity-score-matching

I am new to propensity score matching and got a question regarding the Matchit getting started vignette. In the reporting results section it is stated that
"The estimated effect was $1980 (SE = 756.1, p = .009), indicating that the average effect of the treatment for those who received it is to increase earnings."

However I can't find these values inside the t test of coefficients. Where do I receive these values from?

```
## 
## t test of coefficients:
## 
##                Estimate  Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)  2.6929e+03  3.0762e+03  0.8754   0.38171    
## treat        2.0915e+03  6.7833e+02  3.0834   0.00214 ** 
## age         -3.5164e+01  3.6614e+01 -0.9604   0.33724    
## educ         2.1371e+02  2.0154e+02  1.0604   0.28939    
## racehispan   1.0262e+03  1.4661e+03  0.7000   0.48420    
## racewhite    1.5550e+03  8.2045e+02  1.8953   0.05853 .  
## married      7.4987e+02  1.0759e+03  0.6970   0.48609    
## nodegree    -1.3684e+03  1.2127e+03 -1.1284   0.25960    
## re74        -1.9924e-02  1.4178e-01 -0.1405   0.88830    
## re75         5.9919e-01  1.3929e-01  4.3017 1.977e-05 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a typo that has been fixed. In the future, this would be a good thing to submit as an issue on the `MatchIt` [issues page](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't sure if its a mistake or if I didn't understand how to interpret the values.